# Packaging Kivy Python applications on OSX Yosemite not working

Tags: python, macos, kivy, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package a Kivy/Python application on Yosemite with pyinstaller *(OSX 10.10, Kivy 1.9, pyinstaller 2.1)* and not having much success, via the [Kivy OSX package how-to](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-macosx.html). After troubleshooting my PYTHONPATH to make sure it included Kivy and all the dependencies, I tried just building their demo touchtracer app, since it's used in the example.

Whatever I build into a package for OSX doesn't run. The console just returns:

> com.apple.xpc.launchd[1](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-macosx.html):
>   (com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000017.mypython-app[15589]) Service
>   exited with abnormal code: 255

As far as I can see the specfile build and the .app package build go fine, except for these two different errors while building the specfile:

> WARNING: library user32.dll required via ctypes not found

and then this bit about not finding Python:

```
7246 ERROR: Can not find path @executable_path/../.Python (needed by /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/python)
7246 INFO: Using Python library /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
7246 INFO: Adding Python library to binary dependencies
...
8489 ERROR: Can not find path @executable_path/../.Python (needed by /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/python)
```

I assume it's an issue with the path, but not sure exactly what it's looking for (aside from Python?) or how to remedy this. Otherwise it's finding all the other libraries just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: And for the record, I'm running this via the `kivy pyinstaller.py --windowed --name my_project my_project/main.py` method, since it needs to be run in the kivy environment.

Comment: Never used pyinstaller, I'm writing `pyobjc`-apps and bundle them just fine with `py2app` - maybe that works for you. Somehow.

Comment: deets, i was looking at that. there doesn't seem to be any precedence on building kivy apps with it, but i think it's definitely work looking into.

Comment: It looks like this is an issue with pyinstaller 2.1. I tried switching down to pyinstaller 2.0, it's still not working but for totally different reasons. It looks like downgrading versions resolved the issue of it finding Kivy and Python correctly, it's obviously launching both on build. Now my app launches and tanks right away, gives this in the console:

`6/17/15 1:37:24.996 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.ReportCrash[1360]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.ReportCrash`

Comment: Would be interesting if the build works, but pyinstaller 2.0 was using some obsoleted "launch APIs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So even though I don't have my app working still, I've technically answered this question. For whatever reason pyinstaller 2.1 wasn't able to properly find Python or Kivy. When I downloaded pyinstaller 2.0 and ran that, everything built properly.

Instead of getting those "Can not find path" errors, I now get happy looking output like

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-06-17_9.txt
4618 INFO: [Logger      ] Record log in /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-06-17_9.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
4617 INFO: [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
4618 INFO: [Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
```

So now I just need to troubleshoot and figure out why the app launches and crashes instantly, outputting this to console:

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.ReportCrash[1360]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.ReportCrash
```

That's for another question though, I suppose.